# Atomic clock in kitchen microwave or other random electronics?

Tags: atomic-physics, electronics, technology, atomic-clocks

Is it possible for atomic clocks to be put in anything, say a kitchen microwave? Or a regular wall clock?

If so, why are they not in all clocks?

Is it cost? How much does this tech cost to add to something?

Comment: https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/clocks-frequency-references/3824-chip-scale-atomic-clock-csac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheapest and smallest atomic clocks are usually optically pumped rubidium cell clocks, and you can get some of these models for a few thousand euros, maybe less. Are you willing to spend that much for a wall clock?

In case, consider the following points:

1. Rubidium cell clocks are not primary standards (that is, they do not realize the second according to the International System of Units) and, moreover, due to their operation, they are subjected to drifts (unlike beam or fountain types atomic clocks). Indeed, they drift much less than a quartz clock but, yes, they do drift.
2. They are complex devices and their average lifetime is less than that of a quartz oscillator.
3. Nowadays there are cheap ways to synchronize an oscillator through the GPS navigation system or through the network.

Answer (score 2):

an atomic clock is a very complex and delicate device and hence expensive. its use is thus limited to situations where its accuracy is a necessity.

but you do not need your very own atomic clock. to enjoy most of its benefits, all you really need is a wireless link between an existing atomic clock and a local clock in your house. that link is dirt cheap and is, in fact, a feature of the alarm clock sitting next to my bed at this moment.